# how to pass sql query condition dynamically to @query as param

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

Is it possible to add dynamic sql condition to query annotations

Say when n= : name 
 n != : name 
n like "%:name%"

The formation of condition based on the user input

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
   @Query("select p from Person AS p"
   + " ,Name AS n"  
   + " where p.forename = n.forename "
   + " and p.surname = n.surname"
   + " and n = :name")
   Set<Person>findByName(@Param("name") Name name);
}
```

instead of writing "and n = :name " i want form sql condition dynamically when user select  = , or != or like

"and n != :name "
"and n like '%:name%'"

seems like Filtering option

Comment: You should check for Criteria API or QueryDsl which libraries aims for dynamic criteria generation

Comment: QueryDSL is the best way for you. You can manage your query very well with this plugin

Comment: you could do something like `CASE WHEN :name IS NULL THEN n = n ELSE n = :name END`

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way for Spring Data Jpa  would be using [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) based on JPA Criteria API.